# Sorry the application (app name) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to run the following codes in ADT and whenever i try to run it as an android application , i have the error as stated in the title.

This is the code in the .java file.

```
     package sp.com;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class RestaurantList extends ActionBarActivity {

        private EditText name;
        private RadioGroup restaurantTypes;
        private Button save;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
            restaurantTypes = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.types);

            save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
            save.setOnClickListener(onSave);
        }

        private View.OnClickListener onSave = new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String nameStr = name.getText().toString();

                String restType = "";

                switch (restaurantTypes.getCheckedRadioButtonId()){
                case R.id.chinese:
                    restType = "Chinese";
                    break;
                case R.id.indian:
                    restType = "Indian";
                    break;
                case R.id.western:
                    restType = "Western";
                    break;
                case R.id.indonesian:
                    restType = "Indonesian";
                    break;
                case R.id.korean:
                    restType = "Korean";
                    break;
                case R.id.japanese:
                    restType = "Japanese";
                    break;
                case R.id.thai:
                    restType = "Thai";
                    break;
                }
                String combineStr = nameStr + "\n" + restType;
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), combineStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        };


        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.restaurant_list, menu);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And here is the fragment_restaurant_list.xml file.

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/TableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:stretchColumns="1"
        tools:context="sp.com.RestaurantList$PlaceholderFragment" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name : " />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add :" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/add"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tel :" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/telephone "
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/types"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Type" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/chinese"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Chinese" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/indian"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Indian" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/western"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Western" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/indonesian"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Indonesian" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/korean"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Korean" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/japanese"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:text="Japanese" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/thai"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Thai" />

            </RadioGroup>

        </TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save" />

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the manifest.xml file.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sp.com"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="sp.com.RestaurantList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the logcat :

```
05-03 14:40:33.382: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 2

05-03 14:40:45.852: E/Zygote(32): setreuid() failed. errno: 17

05-03 14:40:47.522: E/BatteryService(60): usbOnlinePath not found

05-03 14:40:47.522: E/BatteryService(60): batteryVoltagePath not found

05-03 14:40:47.522: E/BatteryService(60): batteryTemperaturePath not found

05-03 14:40:47.542: E/SurfaceFlinger(60): Couldn't open /sys/power/wait_for_fb_sleep or /sys/power/wait_for_fb_wake

05-03 14:40:47.642: E/SensorService(60): couldn't open device for module sensors (Invalid argument)

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60): Failure starting core service

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60): java.lang.SecurityException

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60):   at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60):   at android.os.ServiceManagerProxy.addService(ServiceManagerNative.java:146)

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60):   at android.os.ServiceManager.addService(ServiceManager.java:72)

05-03 14:40:54.203: E/System(60):   at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:206)

05-03 14:40:54.233: E/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter

05-03 14:40:54.233: E/EventHub(60): could not get driver version for /dev/input/mice, Not a typewriter

05-03 14:40:54.873: E/SoundPool(60): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg

05-03 14:40:54.893: E/SoundPool(60): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg

05-03 14:40:54.913: E/SoundPool(60): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg

05-03 14:40:54.933: E/SoundPool(60): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg

05-03 14:40:54.933: E/SoundPool(60): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg

05-03 14:40:54.993: E/UsbObserver(60): java.lang.NullPointerException

05-03 14:40:54.993: E/UsbObserver(60):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.init(UsbObserver.java:131)

05-03 14:40:54.993: E/UsbObserver(60):  at com.android.server.UsbObserver.<init>(UsbObserver.java:65)

05-03 14:40:54.993: E/UsbObserver(60):  at com.android.server.ServerThread.run(SystemServer.java:402)

05-03 14:40:55.663: E/ThrottleService(60): Could not open GPS configuration file /etc/gps.conf

05-03 14:40:56.363: E/logwrapper(136): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory

05-03 14:40:56.453: E/logwrapper(138): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory

05-03 14:40:56.473: E/logwrapper(140): executing /system/bin/tc failed: No such file or directory

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sp.com/sp.com.RestaurantList}: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at sp.com.RestaurantList.onCreate(RestaurantList.java:30)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)

05-03 14:41:39.030: E/AndroidRuntime(336):  ... 11 more
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

Thank you so much in advance and as i am a beginner , i will appreciate it if the terms used are simple.

Comment: Whenever you get an "Sorry the application (app name) has stopped unexpectedly" error message displayed you need to take a look at the logcat output

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: this is the console :)

Answer (score 2):

You look up your views in the wrong layout xml, because the name of the posted layout is `fragment_restaurant_list.xml` but you set as the content view:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

Comment: so how am i supposed to make it right? :X

Comment: by setting the correct layout in setContentView method.

Comment: @user3599230 just rename the file or change the code `setContentView(R.layout.fragment_restaurant_list);`

Comment: @enrmarc it still is giving me the process has stopped working error :x